# History - can't reload page (clicking the same link)

Tags: javascript, history.js

How to reload the page using History.js (when clicking the same/active page/link again)?

When you navigate to `/home` in the menu bar, and after the page is done loading you click `/home` again the page doesn't reload??

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

```
History.pushState(data, title, url);
```

When clicking the same link again the page doesn't reload? Can't really figure out why?

Have also tried to use the `replaceState()` method

Comment: It sounds like your browser is caching the web page, and just reloads the stored page when you navigate back to it.

Comment: I don't navigate to go back.. I click the same link and the page doesn't reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentLocation = document.location.pathname + decodeURIComponent(document.location.search);
if (currentLocation == url) {
    console.log("Refresh");
    $(window).trigger('statechange');
} else {
    History.pushState(null, title, url);
}
```